# Game Development for the Xbox

Tags: c#, .net, xna, xbox

Since Microsoft has given XNA the boot, can we still use XNA to make games for sale on Xbox? If not, what is their new alternative to XNA?

Comment: A down-vote? Explain please.

Comment: Please add more details to your question, I think this is at the moment not a really good fit for the SO Q&A format. Usually, questions with 1-2 sentences are quite bad.

Answer (score 1):

Xbox One does not support XNA nor has Microsoft provided an alternative. The best way to get XBone development tools is to join their *Independent Developers Publishing Program*.

http://www.xbox.com/en-us/Developers/id

Comment: you can still publish xna games to indie devs vut it requires a paid memebership.  If youa are a student i believe you can get this memebership free. http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/education/gamedevelopment